# CSS Styling not rendering

Tags: html, css

So I made a Todolist, and to make it more interactive, I want to add this Task Added message when a task is added, but my css styles aren't rendering. It can't be a linking problem as I'm using the style attribute. This is my code:

```css
.added {
            position: fixed;
            top: 95%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            background: rgb(2, 2, 2);
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
```

```html
<div class="added">
Task added <span class="dismiss-ok"> OK </span>
</div>
```

[The styles are empty in the console(image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKFZ6.jpg)

Comment: open F12 and look what happened to your css (you may use `position:absolute` )

Comment: Styles are empty in the console

Comment: do you load the style sheet ?

Comment: I'm using a style attribute not a seperate file.

Comment: The other styles are being rendered, only this one.

Comment: in the example below it works as charm, please check your html file you may have some typo error

Comment: Could you show the style tag content if possible ?

Comment: Ok, there's no typo in my HTML, I just checked, I've no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you are giving, I think you are not loading the CSS file properly. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) you can find how to do it.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="added">
        Task added <span class="dismiss-ok"> OK </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS File - named 'mystyle.css' :

```
.added {
                position: fixed;
                top: 95%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                background: rgb(2, 2, 2);
                color: white;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
```

Comment: I'm using a style attribute not a seperate stylesheet.

Comment: He is using the style tag to add css, and all the other css codes are rendered, only this one isnt rendered

Comment: Here is a working example with style attribute: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-durc1n?file=index.html